# Customized multi-level sorting based on max values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df1:

| Label | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | -1 |
| B | 15 |
| C | 5 |
| B | -5 |
| C | 30 |
| D | 20 |
| D | 11 |

I need to sort the dataframe s.t. it is sorted by the max value for a given Label.
So df2:

| Label | Value |
| --- | --- |
| C | 30 |
| C | 5 |
| D | 20 |
| D | 11 |
| B | 15 |
| B | -5 |
| A | -1 |

I could think of creating another column as the max of each label and then sorting by it (and value). But that method seems a bit slow. Is there a faster/more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `key` parameter by mapping by aggregate `max` in Series `s`:

```
s = df.groupby('Label')['Value'].max()

df = df.sort_values('Label', key=lambda x: x.map(s), ascending=False)
print (df)
  Label  Value
2     C      5
4     C     30
5     D     20
6     D     11
1     B     15
3     B     -5
0     A     -1
```